# Logging in to Salesforce with JSForce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, jsforce

I am using the [JSForce docs](https://jsforce.github.io/document/) in order to create a Javascript app to connect to my Salesforce org. My code is as follows:

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com'
});

var username = 'my-username@domain.com';
var password = 'mypassword';


conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(conn.accessToken);
    console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
    console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
    console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
  });
```

However, when I run it, it appears to do nothing at all. I would expact to see either the access token etc to be logged to indicate success, or an error to indicate failure. But nothing is logged at all.

When I check the login history on my Salesforce org, I can see the attempts, they are successful.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. The instructions are for jsforce v1.x, but I had jsforce 2.x (beta). Fixed by doing this:

```
npm install jsforce@1.11.0
```

Comment: Even though I am using jsforce v1.11.1 in my package.json I am still getting the exact same issue what you've mentioned above. I am using this in a Azure Function where I have written a EventHubTrigger in javascrip that runs on a windowsOS on a NodeJS v18.2 runtime stack - I run this project from local VSCode app and the access token gets printed in my console but the same exact thing does not happen when I execute my azure function in azure portal. Any advise or help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same code working perfectly fine in my demo azure function which cannot be taken to production, So I decided to create a new azure function which I intend to take it to production someday. I just replicated all files from demo project (host.json, function.json, package.json, index.js etc...) into the new the azure function & now the new function errors out - It cannot establish or initiate a connection with my salesforce https://test.salesforce.com even though I have the same code base which is strange. I even used beyond compare app. to compare both projects & it has 0 diff.